# How to use same word 2010 macro for other word documents

Tags: vba, ms-word, word-2010

I have one macro (2010) which I want to use for other word documents, can anyone please help me on this ?

Comment: would be nice if you gave more information. Sample code for the macro could be good. Word document version you use, word document you want to use, etc. It is your job to craft an understandable and accurate question to get an answer.

Comment: your code which work in one version of word, might not work in another one, your understanding is that the problem is not the code, but it might not be correct, some people formulate incorrectly their problem and you spend time tackling the wrong problem. Then the place where you put your word document might depend on the version, and on the type of code you have. Then who knows if what you call 'code' or 'macro' might be an excel formula and so on and so forth. Precise questions make people feel like answering.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to share VBA macros between documents you need to put them into a place where all documents have access to.

A document can access macros in the following locations:

- in the document itself (if it is a macro-enabled document)
- in the attached template (usually this is the Normal.dotm template in your profile under `%APPDATA%\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates`)
- in a global template which is loaded as an add-in into Word.

Probably the easiest way is to just use the Normal template, but of course it depends on what you would like to do. Usually, using the Normal template makes it difficult to organize or share your macros. Then it is better to create your own file and store your macros there.

If you are uncertain I recommend you to read the following article in MSDN, in particular the section *Creating a File to Hold Your Macro*:

> **[Getting Started with VBA in Word 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff604039%28v=office.14%29.aspx)**